# error in uploading the image from angular to nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, angular

My `Html file` is -

```
<form method="post" [formGroup]="orderForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(orderForm.value)" >
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Select Branch Image</label>
        <input type="file" formControlName="branchImg" (change)="onFileChange($event)" class="form-control-file" id="image">
      </div>
</form>
```

and my `.ts file` is -

```
public orderForm: FormGroup;

onFileChange(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.orderForm.patchValue({
          branchImg: reader.result
        });               
      };
    }
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      branchImg: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

and then submit the form.

I am supposed to get the image address and the upload that address in `cloudinary`

But when I am consoling the body in my nodejs app

it gives something like this-

```
branchImg: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCEUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAGccAigAYkZCTUQwMTAwMGE4MjBkMDAwMD and so on.
```

I don't think that it is the images address. Can anyone tell me that what is this? and how to get that image's address which I will upload to cloudinary

**As the Eric suggest -**

my app.js code is

```
router.post('/branch',(req,res) =>{
    const body = req.body;
      const base64Data = body.branchImg.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
      console.log(base64Data);
      fs.writeFile("out.jpg", base64Data, 'base64', function(err,result) {
        console.log(result);
      });
 });
```

it gives `result` as `undefined`

Comment: The bit after "base64," is the image encoded as base64. If the user is uploaded the image, there won't be any address that you can use, you'll need the images data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That basically is a base64 encoding of the image data. What you need to do after you get that is write that to a file, and then upload it to cloudinary

```
//this will write the base64 data as a jpg file to your local disk
require("fs").writeFile("out.jpg", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
    //after you write it to disk, use the callback space here to upload said file
    //to your cloudinary endpoint
});
```

Comment: when I am doing `console.log(result)` , It give undefined output

Comment: sorry, in your callback if you want to see something you'll need function(err, result) rather than just function(err). That being said, you already have the file name out.jpg, so as long as there is no error you saved it properly. Then you send out.jpg to your final destination

Comment: yes I am using `result` as callback, But it gives `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, that function doesn't return a result, just a success or error. So if your error is empty you're good to go. You don't actually need the result for anything. As mentioned previously, you already know the filename up front.

Comment: The answer doesn't change.I didn't have a result in my answer

Comment: It's to save your base64 stream into a jpg file locally. Once you've written the file to disk, you can then upload said file to your service. You still need to wait for the callback to trigger to make sure the file is written in it's entirety